# Ruby OpenSSL RSA decryption failing due to padding check failed

Tags: python, ruby, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to replicate the following python code in ruby.  The python code works fine, the ruby code fails due to "padding check failed".  I can encrypt a string and decrypt it with the private key in Ruby, but the encrypted data I need to work with is being retrieved from elsewhere.  I'm unsure of the library and even language used to encrypt it, but the Python code works.

Working Python code:

```
def decrypt_secret(encrypted_base64, private_key):
  key = RSA.importKey(open(private_key, "r").read())
  pkey = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key, hashAlgo=SHA256)
  encrypted_blob = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encrypted_base64)
  decrypted_string = pkey.decrypt(encrypted_blob)
  return decrypted_string
```

Ruby Code fails "padding check failed"

```
def decrypt_secret(encrypted_base64, private_key)
  key = File.read(private_key)
  pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(key)
  encrypted_blob = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(encrypted_base64)
  decrypted_string = pkey.private_decrypt(encrypted_blob, OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)
  return decrypted_string
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the needed functions contained in the [JOSE gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/jose/) to support SHA256 OAEP.  The following code does the job:

```
require 'jose'
def decrypt_secret(encrypted_base64, private_key)
  key = File.read(private_key)
  pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(key)
  encrypted_blob = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(encrypted_base64)
  decrypted_string = JOSE::JWA::PKCS1::rsaes_oaep_decrypt(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256, encrypted_blob, pkey)
  return decrypted_string
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like Ruby's OpenSSL wrapper exposes the option to change the hash function for OAEP. You would need to change the Python code to use SHA-1 (default):

```
pkey = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
```